# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, json

While converting json file to csv,I got the above error
My code is shown below:

```
import json
import csv
data = open("SRInFlow.json",encoding="utf8")
rows = json.loads(data.read())
r=rows.values()
fieldnames = [b'dateTimeValues', b'timeSeries']
with open('C:/DeepLearning/tensorflowpoc/Codes/SRInFlow.csv', 'w') as f:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    for d in r:
  --->    dict_writer.writerow(d)
```

The error displays in the last line. How to rectify the error? Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on your JSON structure

Comment: Try printing `r` and `type(r)` to get an idea what you are dealing with.

Comment: type(r)  is <class 'dict_values'>

Comment: `r = rows.values() ... for d in r:` is a really bad code-smell that you're trying to iterate over just the row values, yet expect them to behave like a dict(!) Why not just simply iterate the normal way: `for row in rows:`

Answer (score 3):

This error is because you are initialising a dictionary writer `dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)` but then you are passing a normal row containing only the values `r=rows.values()` -> `for d in r:` ->`dict_writer.writerow(d)`, when the writer expects a dictionary including the keys. That is what the error means.

I don't know how your JSON looks but you can try something like this:

```
import json
import csv

data = '{"dateTimeValues": [1,3,4], "timeSeries": [0,0,0]}'
rows = json.loads(data)

r=zip(*rows.values())

fieldnames = ['dateTimeValues', 'timeSeries']
with open('c:/Users/jsz.P3-GROUP/Desktop/shit.csv', 'w') as f:
    dict_writer = csv.writer(f)
    dict_writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for d in r:
        dict_writer.writerow(d)
```

This initialises a simple csv writer `dict_writer = csv.writer(f)`(not dictionary), then inputs the fieldnames as a normal row for the header `dict_writer.writerow(fieldnames)` and finally inserts only the values as in your example.

Note that for my json string I had to transpose the values first as in `r=zip(*rows.values())`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks... but got an another error ''_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int ''. My json data is very large which contains 5-6 years of data  and has two headings dateTimeValues and timeSeries

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550125/python-csv-module-to-write-certain-rows-to-new-file